# FluentValidation rules chaining not stopping at first failure

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a model:

```
public class DTO
{
    public int[] StatementItems { get; set; }
}
```

Which I want to validate that:

1. `StatementItems` is not null
2. `StatementItems` is not empty
3. `StatementItems` does not contain any duplicate IDs

The validation rule chain I created is:

```
RuleFor(x => x.StatementItems).NotNull().NotEmpty().Must(x => x.Distinct().Count() == x.Count());
```

And I have a test as:

```
_validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.StatementItems, null as int[]);
```

When I run the test passing in a null value, I would expect it to fail on the first rule of the chain (`NotNull()`) and stop there. However, it complains that the lamda value used in the `Must()` is null.

Am I wrong in thinking that the `Must()` shouldn't be run if the `NotNull()` fails? If so, how should this rule be written?

Thanks

Comment: I imagine it's complaining because `int[]` is a non-nullable type?

Comment: @EricSondergard the array can be null as I think it's a reference type. But yes, the actual int values are non-nullable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although @NPras's answer did supply my with a solution, I didn't like the fact that I'm duplicating the NotNull rule. After a bit more research on FluentValidation I have implemented it using `DependentRules`:

```
RuleFor(x => x.StatementItems).NotNull().NotEmpty()
            .DependentRules(d =>
                d.RuleFor(x => x.StatementItems).Must(x => x.Distinct().Count() == x.Count())
            );
```

So now the `Must` condition is only fired when the previous two rules are valid.

Answer (score 13):

Check out FluentValidation's [cascade mode](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html#setting-the-cascade-mode). You can make it short-circuit on the first failure like this:

```
this.RuleFor(x => x.StatementItems)
   .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
   .NotNull()
   .NotEmpty()
   .Must(x => x.Distinct().Count() == x.Count());
```

Also, you can configure this in your `AbstractValidator` subclass's constructor. Then you won't need to put it on every rule.

```
public MyInputValidator()
{
  this.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;
}
```

Comment: this answer saved my day

Comment: If `StatementItems` is `int[]?` instead of `int[]` the compiler still gives me a warning, that 'x' may be null here (CS8602 dereference of a possibly null reference). How can we handle this warning?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see in the `FluentValidation` documentation that it actually guarantees short-circuiting.

If you look in its source:

```
public virtual ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<T> context)
{
  ...
  var failures = nestedValidators.SelectMany(x => x.Validate(context));
  return new ValidationResult(failures);
}
```

It will run through *all* the validators (with the `SelectMany()`) and returns a list of errors.

Your only option seems to be to force a check on your `Must` rule.

```
.Must(x => x!= null && x.Distinct().Count() == x.Count())
//or, fluently:
.Must(x => x.Distinct().Count() == x.Count()).When(x => x! = null)
```

EDIT:
I was going to suggest that since `Validate()` is virtual, you could just override it in your validator to make it short-circuit. But then I realised that the `nestedValidators` list is private. So yeah, no..