# FluentValidation :Extension Methods applying the same same rule on multiple properties

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Thanks Hassan for the input but I am looking to achieve the same rule applying for multiple properties.
for example First Name, Last Name and Gender needs to be validated for  the Is Not Null and Is Not Empty checks and it’s a generic checks that most of the properties of class should pass that are going to be validated.
I want to apply the Is Null and Empty check at once with the properties chaining below

*

```
****this.RuleOf<IsNotNullOrEmpty>
.For(y => y.person.FirstName)
.For(y => y.person.LastName)
.For(y => y.person.Gender)****
```

*

Where < IsNotNullOrEmpty > should be the Method name for checking the Null and Empty.

Instead of applying rules to each and every properties for Null and Empty check like below

```
 ****this.RuleFor(x => x.person.FirstName).IsNotNullOrEmpty();****
```

I have made the extension method for the IsNotNullorEmpty but it works on property level.

Comment: I was going to flag as duplicate but let me ask first. Is this (the answer - DependentRules) what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100254/fluentvalidation-rules-chaining-not-stopping-at-first-failure

Comment: The trick to chaining is to return the object the method was originally run on or a new instance of the same type of object based on what the method does.

Comment: Thanks Hassan and Juharr for the inputs.i have modified my requirement  so .please go through it once again.